# Builder C++: XMLDocument Replace Node

Tags: c++, xml, c++builder, xmldocument

I need to replace all nodes with others nodes.

My current node:

```xml
<str name="author">Brad Mc</str>
```

I need to replace it with this node:

```xml
<author>Brad Mc<author>
```

I have this code to replace all nodes with others nodes:

```
IXMLNode* xResultNode = XMLDocument1->DocumentElement->ChildNodes->FindNode("result");
IXMLNode* xDocNode;
IXMLNode* xFieldNode;
IXMLNode* xNewFieldNode;
// <result>
for (int i = 0; i < xResultNode->ChildNodes->Count - 1; i) {
    // <doc>
    xDocNode = xResultNode->ChildNodes->Get(i);
    int count = xDocNode->ChildNodes->Count;
    for (int j = 0; j < count - 1; j++) {
        // <field>
        xFieldNode = xDocNode->ChildNodes->Get(j);
        String FieldName = xFieldNode->Attributes["name"];
        String FieldText = xFieldNode->Text;
        // Create new Node / modify node
        xNewFieldNode = xDocNode->AddChild(FieldName);
        xNewFieldNode->SetText(FieldText);
        // I need to replace xFieldNode with xNewFieldNode
        // how to do that? 
    }
}
XMLDocument1->SaveToFile("./ResponseOutPut.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this code is full of memory leaks and invalid memory access.  `IXMLNode` is a reference counted interface, but you are not managing the reference counts correctly.  You need to replace `IXMLNode*` with `_di_IXMLNode` and let it manage the reference counts for you.

Second, to replace an entire node with a new node, you can use the parent node's [`ChildNodes->ReplaceNode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNodeList.ReplaceNode) method.  You can use the owning document's [`CreateNode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLDocument.CreateNode) method to create the new node.